# Verify presence of MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, perl, testing

I have a perl application that uses a MySQL backend.

**How do I verify that the MySQL and database drivers are accessible?**

I'm currently doing the following, *but I don't know if it is actually a sufficient test* -- I'd hate to find out six months down the line that I'm not doing the right test:

```
use Test::More;

BEGIN { use_ok('DBI'); }
BEGIN { use_ok('DBD::mysql'); }

done_testing();
```

Comment: This is enough to check that connection will be available from Perl side. If you want to check if mysql server is available, you need to connect to it.

Comment: @AlexandrCiornii -- if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Related: [`Test::Database`](http://p3rl.org/Test::Database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough to check that connection will be available from Perl side. If you want to check if mysql server is available, you need to connect to it.

P.S. You can also add version checking for DBD::mysql. For ex. 4.001 fixes serious bug in utf8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks fine to me, but if you want to be sure, you can check for the presence of the actual filepaths in your [%INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC) ie:

```
perl -MDBI -e 'die unless $INC{"DBI.pm"}'
perl -MDBD::mysql -e 'die unless $INC{"DBD/mysql.pm"}'
```

Comment: What I'm uncertain about is that I've tested for all of the modules that need to be tested for.  For instance, I'm not even sure whether I need to test for `DBD::mysql` since none of my code `use`s it (I guess `DBI` does the `use`).